# How to programmatically get resource encoding in Maven

Tags: plugins, encoding, maven, maven-plugin

I am writing a maven plugin and I would like to manipulate some resource files.

To achieve this goal, I would like to take the encoding specified using maven-resource-plugin : how can I programmatically access this encoding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it is a bad idea to access other plugin configuration. Instead you canuse the [same expression](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#encoding) as Maven resource plugin is using and use property substitution in pom.xml.

But if you really want to do that, you will have to get the Maven project instance, find resource plugin and then interpret its configuration, taking into account all parent projects as well. I don't believe Maven provides any easy way to handle that.

Comment: I understand your point, this solution enables to only define encoding once.
Thanks.